# Assumption regarding matrix multiplication in mathematical equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab, transformation

I'm learning about the Polar Sine Transform equation, which is denoted by:

[image]

**Sorry i had to attach an image, as I do not know how to write the integral part in Mathjax**

I'm implementing this in Matlab for an image processing task, $r$ and $\theta$ are **polar coordinates** of an image block, hence **matrices** of **equal dimension**. $n$ and $l$ are integers denoting order and repetition.

Now, I need some help on the $[sin(\pi n r^2) e^{il\theta}]*$ part of the equation. You see I mentioned before that $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates and are represented as a matrix in Matlab for an image block, but I'm not entirely sure if $r^2$ is a **power of the matrix** $r$ or the **element wise power** of $r$.

Could anyone explain if it should be interpreted as ordinary matrix power or element wise? Also, for the exponential part of the equation, $i$ is an imaginary unit, hence i wonder if the "*" complex conjugate symbol is used just for that purpose?

**EDIT**
I forgot to add that for digital images, the PST can be approximately calculated where integral is basically replaced as a sum instead, hence programming wise, we would use the sum.

[image]

$H_{nl}(x,y)$ is the same for $sin(\pi n r^2)$ above.

Comment: So you have a matrix $r$ giving you the value of $r$ for each $(r,\theta)$ point in the 2D mesh and similar for $\theta$? Then it's element based operations all the way.

Comment: Shouldn't it be \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0 ^1 \left[\sin(\pi n r^2)e^{il\theta})\right]^* f(r,\theta)r\text{d}r\text{d}\theta?
ie $\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0 ^1 \left[\sin(\pi n r^2)e^{il\theta})\right]^* f(r,\theta)r\text{d}r\text{d}\theta$

Comment: @Winther so it is element based for $r.^2$ and $i*l .^\theta$? Hence the multiplication of the $sin$ and $e$ would be just an ordinary multiplication then?

Comment: Long time since I did matlab, but IIRC $l*\theta$ should be the same as $l.\theta$ since $l$ is just a real number. And $\exp(A)$ and $\sin(A)$ is always element based exponentiation/sin in matlab. So what I think you want is something like $\sin(\pi*n*r.^2).\exp(-i*l*\theta)$ for this term.

Comment: @Winther thank you. Also, is there a negative before $i$ in exp or is it a mistype? Currently in Matlab there is no element based exponentiation hence  .* exp($-i * l * \theta)$ would do the same job?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up programming and math. In the math, $r$ is a number, which is being integrated over. This is easily seen in this formula because you can see where $r$ is being integrated over. In your implementation, you might define $r$ to be a matrix, so that you can then define a matrix of values of the integrand at each pair $(r,\theta)$ in some grid, and then apply some quadrature rule to this matrix (for fixed $n,l$) to compute each entry of $M$. If you do that, then definitely the $r^2$ in this formula will appear as r.^2 in your program.

Comment: thank you. In this case, my guessing is that for the case of $\theta$ in the exponential part, it would be ordinary multiplication with the imaginary unit i and fixed l? Hence in implementation, it would be $sin(\pi n r.^2) * e^{i l * \theta}$

Comment: Yes that's right (except the multiplication between the sin and the exponential is a .*) Also you can achieve the conjugate in this context by just switching the sign inside the exponential, assuming you don't have any quantities that are unexpectedly complex (like $n$).

Comment: by switching sign do you mean $exp(-i * l * \theta)$ as mentioned by Winther above? If so i totally overlooked that!

Comment: @Maxxx Yep that'll do it.

Comment: thank you very much! Cheers!